# Nginx, how to start service with ngx_http_sub_module enabled

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

How to start Nginx as service with this module?

According to this [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html), it says:

> This module is not built by default, it should be enabled with the --with-http_sub_module configuration parameter.

I don't understand where to enter this command. Is it `nginx service start --with-http_sub_module`? That is so confusing.

When I enter `nginx -V` it shows that `--with-http_sub_module` is available.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you see `--with-http_sub_module` in `nginx -V` output, you can be certain that the module is already built in. So simply use its directives in configuration file, there is no need to do any special magic to load the module itself.

Now as to why documentation says:

> This module is not built by default, it should be enabled with the --with-http_sub_module configuration parameter.

This applies to when you compile nginx yourself, e.g. run the standard `./configure && make && make install`. So the module is not installed by default if you run `./configure` without arguments.

But its worth noting that most *packaged* nginx builds (ones that you get from `yum install nginx` or e.g. `apt install nginx`) would have custom `./configure` command, which (as in your case) already likely had the `--with-http_sub_module` as one of the configuration switches.

Comment: Was looking into this and found it useful the explanation. Thank you.. Upvote

Comment: Have to admit the statement in doc is quite a bit confusing!

Comment: For those looking for it, here is the option declartion fo the Debian package `nginx-core` (default for the `nginx` package): https://salsa.debian.org/nginx-team/nginx/-/blob/master/debian/rules#L95